# How to get the system ioWait

Tags: linux, iowait

How can i get the systems ioWait?
This would be preferable by using info the /proc interface( i guess its written somewhere in there) so an app could detect this, but an external call to exec() from my app would be acceptable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is available in `/proc/stat`.

From the documentation in the kernel source:

> The very first  "cpu" line aggregates
>   the  numbers in all  of the other
>   "cpuN" lines.  These numbers identify
>   the amount of time the CPU has spent
>   performing different kinds of work. 
>   Time units are in USER_HZ (typically
>   hundredths of a second).  The meanings
>   of the columns are as follows, from
>   left to right:
>
> - user: normal processes executing in user mode
> - nice: niced processes executing in user mode
> - system: processes executing in kernel mode
> - idle: twiddling thumbs
> - **iowait: waiting for I/O to complete**
> - irq: servicing interrupts
> - softirq: servicing softirqs
> - steal: involuntary wait

Answer (score 2):

Another way to get the `iowait` is using `iostat` (Debian: [sysstat](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/sysstat)), for example:

```
iostat -c 5
```

will return (every 5 seconds):

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           8.39    0.00   11.42    4.74    0.00   75.46
```

or in JSON format:

```
iostat -o JSON -c 5
```

```json
{
   "sysstat":{
      "hosts":[
         {
            "nodename":"host.example.com",
            "sysname":"Linux",
            "release":"4.15.0-159-generic",
            "machine":"x86_64",
            "number-of-cpus":64,
            "date":"2021/10/27",
            "statistics":[
               {
                  "avg-cpu":{
                     "user":7.32,
                     "nice":0.07,
                     "system":5.60,
                     "iowait":13.59,
                     "steal":0.00,
                     "idle":73.43
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

In here, `iowait` is the same percentage reported by `top`, `glances`, etc.

### Note:

If you run it once, you will get the same values each time, so a way to "fix" it, is to run it at least 2 times and use the last values:

`iostat -c 1 2`

which means: *run it 2 times separated by 1 second*

In `bash` you can get only the `iowait` value with:

`iostat -c 1 2 | awk 'NF { print $4 }' | tail -n 1`

In the case of `JSON`, it will return two children under `statistics` (use the last one).